# Can a reference be null?

Tags: c++, oop, reference, null

I have read from the Wikipedia that:

> “References cannot be null, whereas pointers can; every reference refers to some object, although it may or may not be valid.”

However, I don’t believe this because of following code, which compiles with no error:

```cpp
class person
{
    public:
    virtual void setage() = 0;
};

int main()
{
    person *object = nullptr;
    person &object1 = *object;
}
```

Comment: The article should probably say: "Every reference in a well-formed program refers to an object." Dereferencing a null pointer is of course ill-formed.

Comment: I think what you meant was `person &object1=object;`, which will indeed give you a compiler error (mismatched types).

Comment: And let's not all forget our favorite story about null references: http://www.gotw.ca/conv/002.htm

Comment: @GMan:  Dereferencing a null pointer does result in undefined behavior; undefined behavior does not, however, render a program ill-formed.

Comment: @James: Oops, you're right. Better would be "...reference in a well-defined program... is of course undefined."?

Comment: @GMan:  That sounds better to me.  And, I LOLed at the linked GOTW.  "I cannot teach him; he is drawn to Undefined Behavior:"  sadly, I've known people like that.

Comment: Of course, the program *is* ill-formed. Mostly because of the missing `int`.

Comment: Not again... another null-reference discussion... The standard explicitly states (8.3.2/4) 'a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program'

Comment: "References cannot be null" looks very nice in a textbook until you see your program crash when reading from some reference that came from a dereferenced pointer 10 methods up the chain. The idea of non-nullable references creates a false sense of security and just moves the problem away from the symptoms.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Saying `person &object1=*object` is not the same thing as saying `person &object1=NULL`. Probably the compiler is just not smart enough to find out that you are dereferencing null pointer, but you'll get a runtime error anyway. So they are kind of true still ;)

Comment: Even if the compiler catches this case, there will always be other cases it cannot catch. If you pass the reference through several methods, you'll have the actual program explode very far from where you do the dereferencing in code. This is not just a theoretical concern, I've seen it in production.

Answer (score 22):

In your code:

```
person *object=NULL;
person &object1=*object;
```

you dereference a NULL pointer, so you get undefined behaviour. And to answer your question, there is no such thing as  a NULL reference.

And to address the other part of your question, just because a program compiles, there is no guarantee that it is correct or that it will work. C++ compilers are not required to even attempt to diagnose the kind of error your code contains.

Answer (score 5):

You can have a null reference, not sure why anyone would say otherwise, it is a nasty side effect of some operations. You just can't create one directly.

Comment: I should not be surprised to see downvoting, I can always tell what will set off the stupid people of the planet who think they know everything yet know nothing.

Comment: You can get NULL references *in practice*. Whenever one says, "you *can't* have NULL references", it should read *in a well-formed program*. Besides dereferencing NULL pointers, it might also be possible to create a reference, so that `&ref == NULL` by doing self-initialization:  `int& ref = ref;` (the result could be anything, including NULL, I suppose). - I don't think there'd be anything wrong covering the pragmatic aspect of the problem, but your answer is vague, uninformative and argumentative ("despite what everybody says, [somewhat gibberish point here]").

Comment: @UncleBens, *Null* reference has connotations that aren't supported by the language. I think *invalid* reference better describes the situation. It's a subtle difference but I think it's less controversial.

Answer (score 3):

that would crash your program. Did you try running it? 
doing *object will deference a null pointer, so in fact your reference never gets assigned.

Comment: exelent answer i understood it.

Comment: I don't think it'll crash. It would crash only if you attempt to access members (or methods) of object1.

Comment: It might crash, print 42 or emit blue smoke - simply derefencing a null pointer invokes undefined behaviour so you can't know in advance.

Comment: Just tried with GCC. I created a "NULL reference" to string without a word from the compiler. Received a segmentation fault with GDB only when trying to call a member function. IMO, while you technically "can't have" NULL references, it is important to be aware of the issues when things don't go right. - In any case, the answer is wrong. If the behavior of something is undefined, *there is no guarantee that it will crash*.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can do whatever *you* want in C++. Another example:

```
person &object1 = *( reinterpret_cast<person*>(0) );
```

You are invoking an undefined behavior in the above case, beside the case you mentioned!

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer `reinterpret_cast` to a `static_cast`? (They behave the same in this case of course.)

Comment: @avakar That's what came to my mind when I wrote the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

clang 3.5 even warns on a possible later NULL check of a reference:

```
/tmp/person.C:11:6: warning: reference cannot be bound to dereferenced null pointer in well-defined C++ code; pointer may be assumed to
      always convert to true [-Wundefined-bool-conversion]
if (&object1) {}
~~   ^~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

gcc8 will give a warning about it:

> warning: the compiler can assume that the address of 'object1' will never be NULL [-Waddress]

A small demo:

```
#include <iostream>

class person
{
    public:
        virtual void setage()=0;
};

int main()
{
    person *object=NULL;
    person &object1=*object;

    if (&object1 == NULL) {
        std::cout << "NULL object1" << std::endl;
    }

    if (!(&object1)) {
        std::cout << "NULL object1 " << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Compile and running output:

> g++ -std=c++2a -pthread -fgnu-tm  -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread
>   -pedantic-errors main.cpp -lm  -latomic -lstdc++fs  && ./a.out
>
> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>
> main.cpp:14:18: warning: the compiler can assume that the address of
>   'object1' will never be NULL [-Waddress]
>
> ```
>  if (&object1 == NULL) {
>
>               ^
> ```
>
> main.cpp:18:19: warning: the compiler can assume that the address of
>   'object1' will never be NULL [-Waddress]
>
> ```
>  if (!(&object1)) {
>
>                ^
> ```
>
> NULL object1
>
> NULL object1